# Convert UWP WriteableBitmap to XamarinForms Image

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, uwp

is there a way to convert a UWP WriteableBitmap to a XamarinForms Image? Trying a simple convert ends up with "cannot implicitly convert type WriteableBitmap to Xamarin Forms Image".

Do I have to convert it before to a base64 string? Or how would you handle that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could find [`FromStream`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream/p/System.Func%7BSystem.IO.Stream%7D/) method in the `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource`. For your requirement, you could get stream of `WriteableBitmap` form uwp project via [`DependencyService`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/). And converter it to `ImageSource` in the PCL.

Example:

**Interface**

```
public interface IStreamToImage
{
    Task GetStreamFormUWP(Action<Stream> StreamBlock);
}
```

**implement**

```
public async Task GetStreamFormUWP(Action<Stream> StreamBlock)
{ 
    await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async() => {

       .......

       using (Stream stream = MyBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream()){
       await stream.WriteAsync(sourcePixels, 0, sourcePixels.Length);
       StreamBlock(stream);
    }
 });
}
```

**Usage**

```
await DependencyService.Get<IStreamToImage>().GetStreamFormUWP( (stream) =>
{          
    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nico, actually I was trying something very similar. `Stream str = bm.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    str.CopyTo(ms); ` and then:  `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(ms); ` But the Xamarin Forms image will always be empty.

Comment: @fix I have the similar issue with the above the answer, And Nico told that the soure `PropertyChanged` has not invoked when was set value. It may be a bug.